# Colors and a plotting term document matrix

Tags: r

Following the example of plotting a term-document matrix below,

```
library("tm")

  data("crude")

  tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude, control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                                  removeNumbers = TRUE,
                                                  stopwords = TRUE))

  plot(tdm, terms = findFreqTerms(tdm, lowfreq = 6)[1:25], corThreshold = 0.5)
```

Is there a way to colorize the nodes based on how many vertices they have? Is there an example of making the nodes with more vertices larger or something to that effect as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I appears that the nodes that end up being plotted are of the class `AgNode`. The properties that you can set of the `AgNode` are listed on the `?AgNode` help page. Once you know what properties you would like to set, you can pass a list to a `nodeAttrs` parameter to your plotting command. (EDIT: actually a better list is probably the node attributes description in the [Rgraphviz documentation](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/Rgraphviz/man/Rgraphviz.pdf))

The `nodeAttrs` parameter take a list where each named element of that list corresponds to one of the properties of `AgNode`. At each position, you store a named vector where the name of the vector corresponds to the node name (ie the word in your term matrix) and the value represents the value for that attribute. For example

```
list(
    color=c(futures="blue", demand="red"),
    shape=c(crude="ellipse", budget="circle"),
)
```

So when you wanted to color the terms by the number of vertexes they have, i'm going to assume you mean edges as each word is a single vertex in the graph. So, using your `tdm` object

```
freqterms <- findFreqTerms(tdm, lowfreq = 6)[1:25]
vtxcnt <- rowSums(cor(as.matrix(t(tdm[freqterms,])))>.5)-1
```

I save the terms you wanted, and then I basically copied the code inside the plot command to calculate the correlations with your cutoff of 0.5 to see how many other words each word in this subset is connected to. That's the `vtxcnt` variable. (There may be a more efficient way to extract this but I could not find it). Now I'm ready to assign colors

```
mycols<-c("#f7fbff","#deebf7","#c6dbef",
    "#9ecae1","#6baed6","#4292c6",
    "#2171b5", "#084594")
vc <- mycols[vtxcnt+1]
names(vc) <- names(vtxcnt)
```

Here I grabbed some colors from [ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/). I have 8 values because the values of `vtxcnt` range from 0-8. If you had a wider range or wanted to collapsed categories, you could use the `cut()` command to categorize them. Then I created a named vector `vc` that matches up each word to the appropriate color. `vc` should look like this

```
 head(vc)
 #  ability    accord agreement       ali      also  analysts 
 # "#084594" "#c6dbef" "#2171b5" "#9ecae1" "#f7fbff" "#4292c6"
```

And now we are ready to make the plot

```
pp <- plot(tdm, 
    terms = freqterms, 
    corThreshold = 0.5,
    nodeAttrs=list(fillcolor=vc))
```

So as you can see the customizing of nodes is pretty flexible. You can color them how every you like if you pass the correct values to `nodeAttrs`.

[image: colored TermDocumentMatrix Plot]